# Как получить из компонента TWebBrowser исходный код загруженой страницы?

Tags: delphi, синтаксический-анализ

Как получить из компонента `TWebBrowser` исходный код загруженой страницы?
То есть я сделал процедуру `WebBrowser.Navigate('http://link')`, и как мне извлечь исходный код с получавшийся страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут готовая функция](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/wb_get_html_code.html)

Comment: Увы, но у меня не получается сделать следующее:
<pre><code>
 procedure test;
 var
  S: String;
 begin
  WB_GetHTMLCode(MainForm.WebBrowser1, S);
 end;
</pre></code>

Comment: Ну так возвращается ведь не строка, а набор строк `TStrings`. Просто сделай

`var
 S: TStringList;`

`TStringList` - потомок `TStrings`, который можно нормально использовать.
К `TStrings`, по-моему, можно обращаться как к массиву, т.е `s[0]`, `s[1]` и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

НАДО СОЗДАТЬ ОБЪЕКТ S ПЕРЕД ЕГО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ

var
 S: TStringList;

begin

S := TStringList.Create;

WB_GetHTMLCode(MainForm.WebBrowser1, S);

...

S.Free;

end;

Comment: Есть такая вещь как комментарии.